# syntax highlighting in source blocks

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting

I thought that org-mode highlighted source blocks with the relevant mode. So for example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC clojure
(defn plus [a b]
  (+ a b))
#+END_SRC
```

This would show up with the syntax highlighting one would expect if in a Clojure buffer.

For some reason, my setup is just showing the above example in one monotone of gray.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Org-mode fontifies these blocks if you enable the corresponding setting. Try:

```
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
```

Comment: Thanks. I must've lost this setting when switching machines.

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: Feel free to open a new question for your specific problem.